# evalWithTimeout ignored when calling C / Fortran routines?

Tags: c, r, igraph

I'm working with "igraph" package, and the "evalWithTimeout" function in "R.utils".

I'm trying to do maximal clique detection, which I know it can get terrible (as terrible O(3^n) being n the number of nodes) so I encapsulated in a timeOut, but it gets ignored.

Minimal code to reproduce the problem

```
library(igraph) 
library(R.utils)
g<-erdos.renyi.game(1e6,1e7,type="gnm")
o<-evalWithTimeout(maximal.cliques(g),timeout=1)
```

This should stop after one second. However it doesn't. I wonder if this is due to the use of underlying C / Fortran code (which is what maximal.cliques does). If so, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work with most C code, because R cannot interrupt C code, unless the C code cooperates. `evalWithTimeout` calls `setTimeLimit`, and this is from the manual page from `setTimeLimit`:

> Time limits are checked whenever a user interrupt could occur.
>   This will happen frequently in R code and during `Sys.sleep`, but
>   only at points in compiled C and Fortran code identified by the
>   code author.

It is not trivial to make C code interruptible, because you need to deallocate all allocated memory.

I suggest to report a bug at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues and request to make `maximal.cliques` interruptible.

Comment: But it is rather trivial to make C code interruptible... you just need to put calls to `R_checkUserInterrupt()` in strategic places.

Comment: No, it is not trivial, because you need to deallocate the memory, and that is non-trivial if the C function you called calls other C functions, etc.